# how to make a table start a new column automatically as soon as the specifies number of rows are reached

Tags: html, css

i tried something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>age</th>
  <th>gen</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>M</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>M</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the output i was getting was like

```
name age gen
 A    4   M
 B    5   F
 C    9   M
```

what i want is like it should switch to new column as two rows have been reached like this

```
name age gen name age gen
 A    4   M   C    9   M
 B    5   F
```

i tried using css to limit its width but didnt work

Comment: is is static html or you are using some jaavscript to build and render it?

Comment: its a static html for now

Comment: You tried some html for a javascript problem is confusing. Please update your question with the javascript.

Comment: i have not used js yet

Comment: Then your data should be in an array. So you can do some processing before displaying the table.

Comment: sorry ! I didnt get that completely

Comment: You need to use javascript to render the table then only you can achieve it, if its feasible for you to use javascript to render it then I can suggest solution.

Comment: HTML by definition is a markup language for displaying stuff, like your data. You need a data structure, which can be an array (or an object). You don't have that. Manipulating the DOM directly with literal data is likely a harder problem. So you create a data structure and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: @PawanSingh yeah sure

Comment: @GetSet that was really helpful and i guess your saying this that "this happen without further programming" might make it work

Comment: Sorry @VivekAnand i was actually being a lil hinting (read: sarcastic) that this is a problem that requires programming, which html is simply not.

Comment: HTML has zero built in functionalities to answer your question. You need to write a program. That's what I meant. As in you seem to think that HTML has some magic for sorting or implanting logic. ..... It doesnt. ,,,,,,,,, Are you expecting someone to write the code for you, is that your goal? If so, say it. Wouldn't hurt to be honest about it.

Answer (score 0):

so as pointed out in the comments you should get your hands dirty on JavaScript to solve this problem as the **magic** you're looking for is not available in HTML.

Coming back to the question, to achieve such results the idea is to save your columns and row data into arrays and then further process it with your own rules and generate an HTML for the table dynamically using JS.

For now as it is a static table, what i have done is, i gave the table an ID and using JavaScript i scraped the HTML content inside the table like the rows and the columns and dynamically generated a new table with the rules you have mentioned. You can easily understand what's going on in the code below if you have some knowledge of JavaScript.

```js
function getColumsTimesRepeated(rows,limit)
{
    return (Math.ceil(rows/limit)*limit)/limit;
}

var rowLimit = 2;

var tableData = [];
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var tableHeading = table.children[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML; // extract heading HTML
var tableChildRows = table.children[0].children; 
var tableRowCount = table.children[0].childElementCount - 1; // considering 1st row as table head 

//create an array of static table's rows (The HTML content)  
for(var i=1; i <= tableRowCount; i ++){ 
    tableData.push(tableChildRows[i].innerHTML);
}

// find how many times you need to repeat the columns base don the rowLimit and the number of rows in the table
var columnsTimesRepeated = getColumsTimesRepeated(tableRowCount,rowLimit);

var newTableHeadingHTML = '<tr>';
for(var i=0; i < columnsTimesRepeated; i++){
    newTableHeadingHTML += tableHeading;
}
newTableHeadingHTML +="</tr>";

var newTableRowsHTML = '';
for(var j=1; j <= rowLimit; j++){

        
        newTableRowsHTML += "<tr>";
        var k=j;
        while (k <= tableRowCount){
            newTableRowsHTML += tableData[k-1];
            
            k +=rowLimit;           // skip to the data for currentRow only
        }
        newTableRowsHTML += "</tr>";
}


document.getElementById("newTable").innerHTML = newTableHeadingHTML+newTableRowsHTML;
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>age</th>
  <th>gen</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>M</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>M</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>D</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>O</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>E</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>G</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="newTable">
</table>
```

Try to go through the code and understand it, till then enjoy the hack!